# C Strings Comparison with Equal Sign

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I have this code:

```
char *name = "George"

if(name == "George")
   printf("It's George")
```

I thought that c strings could not be compared with `==` sign and I have to use `strcmp`. For unknown reason when I compile with gcc (version 4.7.3) this code works. I though that this was wrong because it is like comparing pointers so I searched in google and many people say that it's wrong and comparing with `==` can't be done. So why this comparing method works ?

Comment: use `strcmp()`, you are comparing addresses.

Comment: You can check that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253113/strcmp-with-pointers-not-working-in-c .

Comment: @nouney What's UB? I don't see any reason for it.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah there's not reason, my compiler fools me

Comment: For the OP: [Look at this code](https://ideone.com/semWp6), it will show you why it works.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Well I don't understand what are you trying to explain to me.

Comment: @nouney I by mistake typed

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I thought that c strings could not be compared with == sign and I have to use strcmp

Right.

> I though that this was wrong because it is like comparing pointers so I searched in google and many people say that it's wrong and comparing with == can't be done

That's right too.

> So why this comparing method works ?

It doesn't "work". It only *appears to be working.*

The reason why this happens is probably a compiler optimization: the two string literals are identical, so the compiler really generates only one instance of them, and uses that very same pointer/array whenever the string literal is referenced.

Answer (score 10):

Just to provide a reference to @H2CO3's answer:

C11 6.4.5 *String literals*

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

This means that in your example, `name`(a string literal "George") and `"George"` may and may not share the same location, it's up to the implementation. So don't count on this, it may results differently in other machines.

Comment: +1, GCC will put all string literals in .rodata section and is smart enough to eliminate duplicated. :)

Answer (score 5):

The comparison you have done compares the *location* of the two strings, rather than their content.  It just so happens that your compiler decided to only create *one* string literal containing the characters `"George"`.  This means that the location of the string stored in `name` and the location of the second `"George"` are the same, so the comparison returns non-zero.

The compiler is not required to do this, however - it could just as easily create two different string literals, with different locations but the same content, and the comparison would then return zero.

Answer (score 1):

This will fail, since you are comparing two different pointers of two separate strings.
If this code still works, then this is a result of a heavy optimization of GCC, that keeps only one copy for size optimization.

Use `strcmp()`. [Link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

Comment: OP just stated that the strings turned out to be equal. He also knows why `strcmp()` should be used. This is not an answer. It's also wrong, because "you are comparing two different pointers of two separate strings" is not true - for the very reason I explained in my answer.

Comment: Strings are equal, but they are placed in two different memory locations. As a result their pointers are different, and comparison is wrong. If this code still works, then this is a result of a heavy optimization of GCC.

Comment: "but they are placed in two different memory locations" - no, they aren't, I suggest you finally **read** my answer.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, Since they are immutable, they **can** be placed in one address.

Answer (score -1):

If you compare two stings that you are comparing base addresses of those strings not actual characters in those strings. for comparing strings use `strcmp()` and `strcasecmp()` library functions or write program like this. below is not a full code just logic required for string comparison.

```
void mystrcmp(const char *source,char *dest)
{
    for(i=0;source[i] != '\0';i++)
        dest[i] = source[i];
   dest[i] = 0;

}
```

Comment: This looks more like a `mtystrcpy` to me.