# Get address of a string-constant in C

Tags: c, string, constants

I would like to get the address of an string-constant in C.

```
 char * const MYCONST = "StringString";
```

As far as I know consts are "saved" in the Text/Code Segment of the memory. 
When I try to get the address of the first element in MYCONSt:

```
 printf("%p\n",&(MYCONST));
```

As result I get  0x7fff15342e28, which is in the stack and not in the Text/Code segement. 
Can anybody please help me get the address of a string-constant in C?

//edit
I can't find the correct answer so far: When I write

```
  char * const MYCONST1 = "StringString";
  printf("Address of MYCONST1: %p\n",MYCONST1);

  char * const MYCONST2 = "StringString";
  printf("Address of MYCONST2: %p\n",(void*)MYCONST2);
```

this is the output:

Address of MYCONST1: 0x400b91

Address of MYCONST2: 0x400b91

But they should have different addresses, because the are different constants.
Can anybody explain me while the result has a length of seven and not 0x7fffa5dd398c like a locale variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** //edit I can't find the correct answer so far: When I write

```
char * const MYCONST1 = "StringString";
printf("Address of MYCONST1: %p\n",MYCONST1);

char * const MYCONST2 = "StringString";
printf("Address of MYCONST2: %p\n",(void*)MYCONST2);
```

this is the output:

```
Address of MYCONST1: 0x400b91

Address of MYCONST2: 0x400b91
```

But they should have different addresses, because the are different constants.

---

**A:**  Since both the pointers point to same string literal. Compiler optimizes and let them share the same data and hence same address. Try compiling your code with

```
gcc program_name.c -O
```

and see. You will see the addresses different.

Relative: [Addresses of two pointers are same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088153/addresses-of-two-pointers-are-same/19094304)

Answer (score 6):

Since `MYCONST` is already a pointer, you do not need an ampersand. All you need is a cast to `void*` for the `%p`:

```
printf("%p\n",(void*)MYCONST);
```

With an ampersand, you print the address of the `MYCONST` local variable (you need a `void*` cast there as well, otherwise the address may print incorrectly), which is indeed located on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%p\n",(void *) &MYCONST);
```

prints the address of the `MYCONST` pointer variable.

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) MYCONST);
```

prints the value of the `MYCONST` pointer variable.

Comment: When I try to get the address of the pointer value:  0x7fff70f54bb8. I think that can't be correct, because constants are in the code segment and this address belongs to stack?

Answer (score 1):

Address of the first character of a C string is in the variable of the string itself, i.e. MYCONST in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * const MYCONST = "StringString";
```

initializes a pointer `MYCONST`, making it point to the memory where this string literal is stored.
To print an address of this string, use the pointer's value:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*) MYCONST);
```

instead of

```
printf("%p\n", (void*) &MYCONST);
```

which prints the address of pointer itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%p\n",(void*)MYCONST);
```

Will print the address of the first element of string `MYCONST` points to.

The reason I didn't put `&` before `MYCONST` is because `MYCONST` is already a pointer.

If you need to print the `address of Pointer`, then you need to do like `&MYCONST`.

Comment: No. It will not print the address of`MYCONST`. It will print the address of first character of the string.

Comment: @haccks yep I made correction. It was a typo. I was trying to answer quickly but other people were faster then me :P