# c program prints same address for strings, unexpected output of c program

Tags: c

I was trying following code.

```
           #include <stdio.h>


           int main() {
                   char *s2 = "Test";
                   char *s3 = "Test";


                   printf("\n%u",s2);
                   printf("\n%u",s3);

                   return 0;
           }
```

When I executed this code I got following output.

```
           4196492
           4196492
```

Why the output is so.? It prints same address for s2 and s3

Comment: You have five `printf`s and only two lines of output. What is your output, really?

Comment: Related Question: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333602/get-address-of-a-string-constant-in-c/19334244#19334244

Comment: "It prints same address for s2 and s3" -- Yes, so? Why would you expect them to be different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most compilers, when a string value is directly assigned to a pointer, it’s stored in a read-only block (generally in data segment).

This is shared among functions.

when you say `char *str  =  "Test";`

"Test" is stored in a shared read-only location, but the pointer `str` is stored in a read-write memory and `str` is pointing to that memory location in the read-only location. When you assign the same string to a different pointer, 
say `char* str2 = "Test";`. The `str2` pointer will point to the same address from the read only memory location, which is why the output is same.

The following code will fail; the program will crash, because you are trying to change the read only string:

```
int main() {
    char *str; 
    str = "Test";     // Stored in read only part of data segment
    *(str+1) = 'n'; // Trying to modify read only memory. segfault
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Creating a string using a `char` array is different from creating a string with a `char` pointer; the `char` array will be created just like other types of arrays in C.

For example, 
              If `str[]` is an auto variable then string is stored in the stack segment.
              If `str[]` is a global or static variable then stored in the data segment.

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "Test";  // Stored in stack segment like other auto variables
    *(str+1) = 'n';   //This is fine
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The following code clarifies things:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char s1[] = "Test"; //Global in data segment

int main() {
    char *s2 = "Test"; //Read only 
    char *s3 = "Test"; //pointed to a string in a Read only memory 
    char s4[] = "Test"; //stack segment
    char s5[] = "Test"; //another array in stack segment

    printf("\n%p",s1); 
    printf("\n%p",s2);
    printf("\n%p",s3);
    printf("\n%p",s4);
    printf("\n%p",s5);

    return 0;
}
```

this will print something like this.

```
6294408
4196492
4196492
1092092672
1092092656
```

So you can see that addresses of `s1`, `s4` and `s5` are different.

Answer (score 0):

Because a `String` is automatically stored as a reference type in memory, It's treated as an address itself. If you store "TEST" as another pointer, that pointer will point to the same address where "TEST" was stored previously.