# objc_getAssociatedObject returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c-runtime

Here's how I set the associated object:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(navigationItem, "rightButton", leftButtonView, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

and here's how I get it:

```
UIButton *favoriteButton = (UIButton *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self.navigationItem, "rightButton");
```

The object is a `UIButton` in both instances, and I have the `#import "objc/runtime.h"` in both classes.

The thing is, it used to work, but now for some reason it returns `null`. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I'm setting the associated object in another class by passing the `navigationItem` as an argument:

```
+ (void)setNavigationBarTitle:(NSString *)title 
                andLeftButton:(NSString *)leftButtonTitle 
                 withSelector:(SEL)leftSelector 
               andRightButton:(NSString *)rightButtonTitle 
                 withSelector:(SEL)rightSelector 
                    andTarget:(id)target 
            forNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)navigationItem;
```

I use this convenience method in my utility class to set up a navigation bar for each new view controller in my app. When creating the navigation bar buttons, I associate them with the navigation item - my first line of code in the question.

Comment: Also, `navigationItem` and `self.navigationItem` aren't necessarily the same thing. It's impossible to tell without more context.

Comment: Damn it, I copied the wrong line... I am actually doing this for both left and right button, so there is a set object command for rightButton as well - edited. So, the problem is not there, but thanks for noticing :)

Comment: Have you verified that `navigationItem` is the same object (see godel9's comment above)? Note that each view controller has its own navigation item!

Comment: Yes, it's the same `self.navigationItem`. I'm referring to it without `self` because I'm passing it as a method argument to another class, that is a class method of a utility class that does not get released, or so I assume that it doesn't. I have added the method with some more explanation in my edit.

Comment: Just to make sure: You are not calling `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` anywhere, are you?

Comment: Bingo - that's it! I do actually call it, although it's in yet another class. `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` takes an argument `id object`, and it's not `navigationItem` that I pass, and certainly not _that_ `navigationItem`. Either way, removing this call solved the problem. If you would put an explanation into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. And thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote a [famous person](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes):

> Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth.

Since all the other guesses were wrong, the only other source of the problem that I can think of is that you are calling `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` at some point. In your question you say that your code used to work, so we must assume that somewhere something changed, causing the execution path to suddenly take a different turn.

- Possibility 1: The execution path now goes through that call to `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` where before it didn't.
- Possibility 2: You already called `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` before, but now you are passing a different value to the function.

It's impossible to say which one of those two it is.

You say in your comment that you do not pass the `navigationItem` in question and ask for an explanation. Unfortunately I cannot provide one. With the knowledge I currently have, I must assume that either your claim or the [Apple docs for the function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) are incorrect. Since `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` has worked for me in the past, I naturally tend to believe Apple :-)

I might ask: How did you verify that you do not pass the wrong object to the function? My suggestion: Add two `NSLog` statements to the code, just before you call `objc_getAssociatedObject()` and `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()`, where you print the pointer of the object that you are passing to the two functions.

Comment: The reason I know I'm not passing the same object is because I am passing an `NSDate` object to `objc_removeAssociatedObjects()` which is obviously not a `navigationItem` :) Anyway, thanks again for finding my problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a shot in the dark, because I could not reproduce the issue. The problem might be
that the `key` argument of `objc_set/getAssociatedObject()` is a unique *pointer*.

So your code would not work if the two different classes use strings
`"rightButton"` at different memory locations. The strings have the same contents,
but the pointer is different.

In any case, you should ensure that the identical *key* is used for setting and retrieving
the associated object:

- In a common header file (or in the .pch file) put an `extern` declaration:

  ```
  extern const void *rightButtonKey;
  ```
- In *exactly one* .m file define the variable. The "self-reference" guarantees that the pointer has a unique value:

  ```
  const void *rightButtonKey = &rightButtonKey;
  ```
- Then use it like

  ```
  objc_setAssociatedObject(navigationItem, rightButtonKey, leftButtonView, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
  ```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I am using the same key. The solution appeared to be different - see comments below my question.

Comment: @artooras: OK, that was a good catch of "herzbube" and I am glad that your problem is solved. - But even if I repeat myself: Two string literals `"rightButton"` in two different files do not necessarily have the same address. So even if it is a problem *now*, I would recommend to change the code. - Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088153/addresses-of-two-pointers-are-same.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I obviously didn't think that far. Would using a string `#define`d in `Project-Prefix.pch` be a move in the right direction? As I'm using this key in multiple different classes/instances.

Comment: @artooras: No, using `#define RIGHT_KEY "rightButton"` would make no difference, because that is expanded by the preprocessor. - Usually constant strings with the same contents are put at the same memory address by the linker, but you cannot rely on that.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is definitely outside my humble amateurish knowledge, but I'll follow your suggestion and refactor my code.

Answer (score 2):

You use different keys: you set object for key `"leftButton"` and get for `"rightButton"`.

Comment: It is rightButton, it was a copy-paste mistake of mine.. Please see comment under my question