# C : how to free a box in a char **array and put inside a pointer to another box

Tags: c

i've a char **array like this one : 
`{"first", "and", "second", "and", "third"}` 
and i'd like to free(array[3]) and put the pointer to array[1] inside. (because it's the same string). 
i tried but the pointer wasn't modified. Can you help me pls, thanks.

Comment: You must not use `free()` on a pointer that wasn't returned by `malloc()`. It causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please click [edit] and copy-paste the code that you tried unsuccessfully. Then select the code, click curly braces above the text editor, and click [Save].

Comment: it's an example here, obviously my array was returned by malloc() .

Comment: Not the array, the string literals that the elements point to.

Comment: just recreate the array minus the literal u do not need, new size would be array[4] instead of array[5]

Answer (score 0):

You can't free a pointer that wasn't allocated dynamically with `malloc()`. Just reassign the pointer without using `free`:

```
array[3] = array[1];
```

This won't likely save any memory, because string literals are allocated statically. And some implementations will merge equal string literals, see [Addresses of two pointers are same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088153/addresses-of-two-pointers-are-same), so it's effectively done the assignment that you want.

Comment: ok thanks, finally my code was correct, just i was doing printf("%p",&array[i]) instead of printf("%p",array[i])