# what happed whene "aa" string assign to a integer variable?

Tags: c, type-conversion

i got below code , i got same value from both variable but assignment b is throw a error and what is the value is it after print ,the  value is 134513904 from both variables what is this

```
int a=(int)"aa",b="aa";
printf("%d,%d",a,b);

if.c: In function ‘main’:
if.c:6:19: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
 cast [enabled by default]
 int a=(int)"aa",b="aa";
                   ^
134513904,134513904
 shell returned 19
```

Then:
  printf("%s:%s",a,b);
  it print string =>aa:aa

Comment: This warning should almost always be considered as an error.

Comment: can you please tell what is error and what is warning? how you say warning is consider to be error.

Comment: Error: you did something completely wrong and the program cannot be compiled. Warning: you did something wrong but you might get away with it if you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addresses of two char pointers to different string literals are same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088153/addresses-of-two-char-pointers-to-different-string-literals-are-same)

Comment: 'KP Creations' asked the same, an hour or so ago.

Answer (score 0):

> the value is 134513904 from both variables what is this

It is the address of location where string `aa` is stored. That is only one copy of `aa` is stored into 'ready-only' section and its address is stored in `a` and `b` variables.

Since `int` are not supposed to hold the address, compiler is throwing warning.

Comment: both   a and b variables print the same address  .How it is possible?

Comment: @HemaKrish Only one copy of `aa` is stored as part of read-only section.